# How do I add a custom wallet to the Safe UI?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I know that the Safe UI is open-sourced & I can fork the project.

If I wanted to add a custom wallet to the UI where would I do that?

Does it already support adding a custom wallet?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to support a custom wallet on [the Gnosis Safe web app](https://app.safe.global) is to integrate it with [WalletConnect](https://walletconnect.com), which allows you to connect your custom wallet to the Safe web app using a QR code.